# Integral in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 3 equations:

`f = (exp(-x.^2)).*(log(x)).^2`
`g = exp(-x.^2)`
`h = (log(x)).^2`

The interval is:

`x = 0.05:10`

I am able to correctly plot the equations but when I try to find an integral, it says that there is an error.

The code I used to find an integral is:

`integral(f,0,Inf)`
`integral(g,0,inf)`
`integral(h,0,10)`

The integrals for f and g are from 0 to infinity and the integral for h is from 0 to 10. None of my code to find integrals works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define f,g,h as functions like shown below. See documentation of integral(), it takes a function as its first argument. [Matlab integral documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html)

```matlab
x = 0.05:10
f = @(x) (exp(-x.^2)).*(log(x)).^2
g = @(x) exp(-x.^2)
h = @(x) (log(x)).^2
integral(f,0,Inf)  % 1.9475
integral(g,0,inf) % 0.8862
integral(h,0,10) % 26.9673
```

```
h = @(x) (log(x)).^2
```

This syntax is called anonymous functions, basically they are nameless functions. In above case it takes x as input and returns log(x) squared.
From now on h is a function and it can be used like this.

```
h(1)  % will be equal 0
```

For more on anonymous functions refer to matlab anonymous functions guide:
[Anonymous Functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html)